# Empty posts when refresh page [ Double Submission ] ( PHP/MYSQL )

Tags: php, mysql

Im new in MYSQL & PHP so don't mind me about my stolen code XD
I want to publish simple posts by using PHP/HTML & saving on Database.

Ayway here is the file that i've created to post stuff on home.php

**admin.php**

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dblogin";

     $newsTitle = null;
     $newsShortDescription = null;
     $newsFullContent = null;
     $newsColor = null;
     $newsIcon = null;
     $users_website = null;
     $users_comment = null;

    if(isset($_POST['btn-post']))
    {
     $newsTitle = $_POST['news_title'];
     $newsShortDescription = $_POST['news_short_description'];
     $newsFullContent = $_POST['news_full_content'];
     $newsColor = $_POST['news_color'];
     $newsIcon = $_POST['news_author'];
    }

    $newsTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($newsTitle);
    $newsShortDescription = mysql_real_escape_string($newsShortDescription);
    $users_website = mysql_real_escape_string($users_website);
    $users_comment = mysql_real_escape_string($users_comment);

    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO info_news (news_title, news_short_description, news_full_content, news_author, news_color)
    VALUES ('$newsTitle', '$newsShortDescription', '$newsFullContent', '$newsIcon', '$newsColor')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    $conn = null;
    ?> 

      <form method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_title" placeholder="Title" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_short_description" placeholder="Description" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_full_content" placeholder="Full Content" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_color" placeholder="Color" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_author" placeholder="Icon" required />
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="btn-post" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
               Post
            </button>
          </div>
          <br />
      </form>
```

Thank you :)

I want to make kind of a simple blog, only Title, Short Description and so... It works while i make new posts, but when i refresh it shows an empty post. Here is a pic: [Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2seK.png) also i've tried to edit the admin.php ( By looking other questions on SOF )

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dblogin";

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO info_news (news_title, news_short_description, news_full_content, news_author, news_color) VALUES (:news_title, :news_short_description, :news_full_content, :news_author, :news_color)");
$stmt->bindParam(':news_title', $news_title);
$stmt->bindParam(':news_short_description', $news_short_description);
$stmt->bindParam(':news_full_content', $news_full_content);
$stmt->bindParam(':news_author', $news_author);
$stmt->bindParam(':news_color', $news_color);
$stmt->execute($_POST);
?> 

  <form method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_title" placeholder="Title" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_short_description" placeholder="Description" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_full_content" placeholder="Full Content" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_color" placeholder="Color" required />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="news_author" placeholder="Icon" required />
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="btn-post" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">
           Post
        </button>
      </div>
      <br />
  </form>
```

By looking some other questions on stackoverflow but still no luck ;/

Comment: first off, you're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_real_escape_string()` and PDO, why is that? You can't.

Comment: Wow, this was fast, wasn't expecting someone to reply like this XD, may you give me more details, because im newbie at PHP&MYSQL

Comment: read http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements and then use a header to redirect on successful submission and use conditional `empty()/isset()`. But you can't "echo" and use a header at the same time.

Comment: You could also alter your columns to NOT NULL and handle on the errors. I've given you enough now to fix your code.

Comment: Yes you did, thank you a lot :)

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: As i said, when i refresh the page, it posts something empty... :/

Comment: And expected behaviour is to post earlier inserted values? Or you do not want to make a second post while refreshing the page?

Comment: @Reloecc I want to make kind of a simple blog, only Title, Short Description and so... It works while i make new posts, but when i refresh it shows an empty post.
Here is a pic: http://i.imgur.com/Qj2Oo1l.png

also i've tried to edit the admin.php ( By looking other questions on SOF )

Comment: 4th' posts is what im trying to say ( Empty post )
5,6,7 are re-submitted when i refreshed the page...

Comment: Here you can see all files, http://hapwebsite.github.io/sow/

Comment: why was this question upvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not an empty post what makes the empty row inserted, try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-post']))
{
$newsTitle = $_POST['news_title'];
$newsShortDescription = $_POST['news_short_description'];
$newsFullContent = $_POST['news_full_content'];
$newsColor = $_POST['news_color'];
$newsIcon = $_POST['news_author'];

$newsTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($newsTitle);
$newsShortDescription = mysql_real_escape_string($newsShortDescription);
$users_website = mysql_real_escape_string($users_website);
$users_comment = mysql_real_escape_string($users_comment);
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql = "INSERT INTO info_news (news_title, news_short_description, news_full_content, news_author, news_color)
VALUES ('$newsTitle', '$newsShortDescription', '$newsFullContent', '$newsIcon',   '$newsColor')";
// use exec() because no results are returned
$conn->exec($sql);
echo "New record created successfully";
$conn = null;
}
```

I moved the "}" after $conn = null; ;)

---

And BTW, you should redirect after each POST. So POST is not sent once more on page refresh.

And you can't redirect while the content was "echoed" already. It will work for a while thanks to buffer, but when the header will grow in its size (like 4kB, depends on server settings) it will fail one day. (saw it few times in github you posted)

Comment: Yay! XD You fixed. Now what is left is to end session and redirect to a new page.

Thank you a lot :)

Comment: Anyway im not trying to sell this to anyone or to get any money from it. Its also on GitHub, you can get the code and do whatever you want :)

Comment: I am sorry I have to say that, but your code is kind of unsellable. Keep learning, glad to help you :)

Comment: I was always in Front-End, but i like to do stuff, so i was just playing with it first, then boom i thought why not. Also yea i have to clean that code cuz is messy af. XD